# consideration of accepted answers for tag-badges

Tags: discussion, feature-request, accepted-answer, tag-badges

Example for a bronze badge:

`[XYZ]` badge Earned 100 upvotes for at least 20 answers in the `XYZ` tag.

I see many answers that are just accepted but not upvoted. Shouldn't accepted answers also be valued?

I agree that upvotes and acceptance aren't the same. But I think accepted answers are more significant practically. Why isn't accepted answers' count considered while awarding badges for tags?

**Update:** I would recommend considering non-voted accepted answer as +1 for tag-badges (something like this 95 upvotes and 5 accepted(0) answers for atleast 20 answers in the 'XYZ' tag.)
I do not intend to recommend ones that have already recieve some upvotes.

Though there are badges like `unsung hero` and `tenacious` are awarded for such category of answers.. they are general tags and they don't acknowledge one's contribution to a technology/domain

Comment: because we already have another badge for Zero score accepted answers: [tenacious](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/225/tenacious)

Comment: @WouterJ And its big brother [Unsung Hero](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/226/unsung-hero).

Comment: But wait! They are generic badges .. they don't acknowledge one's contribution to a technology/domain!

Comment: IMHO considering non-voted accepted answer as +1 for those, it might make sense. But not the ones that recieve some upvotes :-/

Comment: @To_Anonymous, I am interested to discuss about how valid my suggestion is.. So please let me know your thoughts on downvoting. I accept downvotes, but just let me know, what makes it downvote worthy.

Comment: It wasn't me, but [downvotes are different on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Accepting an answer means it helped the OP solve his problem. The post's score represents the community's opinion on the helpfulness of the post.

I value the community's opinion much more than I value the OP's (no offence OPs, you're awesome!).

The point is to have someone give you a thumbs up for your answer, you need to post helpful answers to get the badge, not only answers that'll solve the very specific problem presented in the question.